# EPPlus from Matlab: when creating chart, eShapeStyle missing

Tags: c#, excel, matlab, epplus, epplus-4

to write data from Matlab 2015b to Excel files I'm using the .NET EPPlus library (v4.1, http://epplus.codeplex.com/). Reading and writing data all works. Formatting as well. However, when creating charts, I bump into an error message that I cannot resolve. Let `ws_chart` be the sheet object, then when calling

```
ws_chart.Drawings.AddChart('Chart1', OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.Chart.eChartType.ColumnStacked);
```

The following error message appears

```
Message: The namespace for the type 'eShapeStyle' does not exist. MATLAB requires all .NET types to be within a namespace.
Source: dotnet/cli
HelpLink:
```

I have found that `eShapeStyle` is defined in [`EPPlus/Drawing/ExcelShape.cs`](http://epplus.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#EPPlus/Drawing/ExcelShape.cs) as an `enum`, but using various imports did not work. I'm using right now

```
import System.Drawing.*
import OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.*
import OfficeOpenXml.Style.*
```

I also do not see a namespace `OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.ExcelShape` in Matlab. Can anyone help me with this?

PS: I know I could also use the ActiveX interface, but I find it to be slow and does not let me use Excel while Matlab is writing via this protocol.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of a colleague, I've just found the solution. Turns out I was pretty close, and the Matlab error message was pointing in the right direction. The C# `enum eShapeStyle` is not defined in a namespace, hence Matlab does not load it (MATLAB requires all .NET types to be within a namespace). We have moved it inside `namespace OfficeOpenXml.Drawing`, recompiled the dll and now it works.